# I don't know how to retrieve the currently selected value in a field

Tags: javascript, html

does anyone know how to get the currently selected value from the select field? I have no idea how to do it, I tried many ways?

Comment: And... What did you try?!

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: `document.querySelector("#<element id>").value`

Comment: @Seabyte It doesn't matter anyway since it doesn't work at all anyway.

Comment: @Dima I want to be able to perform some operations on the child that would be currently selected in the selector.

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log(document.getElementById('mySelect').value)
})
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
</select>

<button id="myButton" type="button">Show Selection</button>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I already got the answer I wanted!